# how can I run "cut" command in my ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, shell

I want to run a bash shell script file in my iPad.
there is a `cut` in the script.
but the shell can not find the command.
What package should I install?

Comment: see http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/textproc.html

Answer (score 0):

`coreutils` also known as
[GNU Core Utilities](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities)